# jasper report via laravel - show report in the website html/php

Tags: php, html, angularjs, laravel-5, jasper-reports

I am using jasper report iReport tool to generate some reports from the database.

All done, I am using a library called Lavela/jasperPHP to generate reports via API and export them to pdf, xls ...

My problem is, I want to open the report in a frame or container in my website, the situation now is that i can download reports to pdf and xls, or open the report in html page but not in my website template in a iframe or container or an element.

Any help ?

THIS IS MY PHP CONTROLLLER USING LARAVEL 5.1

```
    $output = public_path() . '/report/'.time().'_CancelAck';
    $output = public_path() . '/report/'.time().'_CancelAck';
    $ext = "pdf";
    $data_file = public_path() . '/report/CancelAck.xml';
    $driver = 'xml';
    $xml_xpath = '/CancelResponse/CancelResult/ID';

    \JasperPHP::process(
        public_path() . '/report/report1.jrxml', 
        $output, 
        array($ext),
        array(),
        array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' =>'',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'database' => 'test',
  'port' => '3306',
 ),
        array('data_file' => $data_file, 'driver' => $driver, 'xml_xpath' => $xml_xpath),                   
        false,
        false
    )->execute();

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.time().'_CancelAck.'.$ext);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($output.'.'.$ext));
    flush();
    readfile($output.'.'.$ext);
    unlink($output.'.'.$ext);

}
```

}

this is my routes :

```
  Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('welcome');
  });

Route::get('getreportService/','ReportController@getReport');
```

when i call the service from the url i get the report as i want, but i need to show this report in my website.

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting the server to create downloadable content.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.time().'_CancelAck.'.$ext);
```

You need to find the proper header for it to return html/css content.